# Drupal 8 memcache :- is any one installed memcache module in drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

View(active tab)
Edit
Status message Forum topic Drupal 8 memcache :- is any one installed memcache module in drupal 8 has been created.
Posted by dwivedi017 on 22 May 2017 at 11:14 UTC
Is any one installed memcache module in drupal 8 ? Please let me know I am getting errors while installing memcache moule.

Error is :-

[Mon May 22 16:34:09.466660 2017] [:error] [pid 4812:tid 1656] [client ::1:60911] Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Component\Serialization\Exception\InvalidDataTypeException: "A YAML file cannot contain tabs as indentation at line 8 (near "\t")." at D:\PHP server\xampp-win32-5.6.30-0-VC11\xampp\htdocs\drupal_8_4\core\lib\Drupal\Component\Serialization\YamlSymfony.php line 39, referer: http://localhost:8012/drupal_8_4/admin/modules
[Mon May 22 16:34:49.425660 2017] [:error] [pid 4812:tid 1648] [client ::1:60913] Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Component\Serialization\Exception\InvalidDataTypeException: "A YAML file cannot contain tabs as indentation at line 8 (near "\t")." at D:\PHP server\xampp-win32-5.6.30-0-VC11\xampp\htdocs\drupal_8_4\core\lib\Drupal\Component\Serialization\YamlSymfony.php line 39, referer: http://localhost:8012/drupal_8_4/admin/modules

Comment: Can we integrate memcache with drupal 8 ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. We can integrate memcache with Drupal 8. And it works perfectly fine.

From your error, it seems that in one of your module, there is a syntax error in yaml file. Extra tab is there. It is not evident from your posted error that the issue is with memcache module. 
Check in your custom module's yaml file for extra tab at line 8. 
This could resolve the issue.